# Titanium scrollview

Tags: scrollview, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a question about `scrollview` for **appcelerator titanium**, I want to scroll labels inside `scrollview`:

**scrollpage.xml**

```
    <View id="content" layout="vertical" top="100dp" width="100%">


        <ScrollView contentWidth="Ti.UI.SIZE" contentHeight="Ti.UI.SIZE" top="10dp" id="svc" height="48dp" backgroundColor="#ff0000" >
        </ScrollView>
    </View>

</Window>
```

**scrollpage.js**

```
for ( i = 0; i < 19; i++) {

    var scrollLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        width : Ti.UI.SIZE,
        height : '40dp',
        font : { fontSize : 14 },
        color:'#000',
        text : 'Portfolio'+i,
        id:'label_'+i,
    });

    $.svc.add(scrollLabel);
}
```

**The result**
[image: result]

I tried `ScrollableView` but I want many items showing directly on screen.

My aim is to achieve this :

[image: Scroll labels horizontally]

Please explain what did I do wrong! Thank you!

Comment: What is the result you want? Can't help you if I don't know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I want scroll labels horizontally

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because by default the layout of a ScrollView is composite. So, if you want different layout, add `layout="horizontal"` on your ScrollableView to place your child element :

```
<ScrollView contentWidth="Ti.UI.SIZE" contentHeight="Ti.UI.SIZE" top="10dp" id="svc" height="48dp" backgroundColor="#ff0000" layout="horizontal"></ScrollView>
```

More information here about layout : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Layouts,_Positioning,_and_the_View_Hierarchy-section-29004895_Layouts,Positioning,andtheViewHierarchy-Layoutmodes